# mvc4 having password value shown in page source any risk

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page were user's can edit they're information and the password is needed to be displayed they're because it is required in the model

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string password { get; set; }
```

and in order to use **if (ModelState.IsValid)** I obviously have to show the password but it is hidden inside the edit view **@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.password)** is there any danger to this from a hacking perspective? The value of the password can be seen once you go to page-source it is hashed and is there anyway to maybe hide the value from being seen in the page source?

Answer (score -1):

I think you allowed user to change their password.you dont't need to display password in your view .At view ,;t has field "Input Old Password" , when user click save , you can use Ajax to check valid password of current user . I will solve your issue.
Best regards!